# IOS build fails with error invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate Google Firebase for push notification in my Ionic App.
I am trying to build it for IOS platform.
I have download GoogleSerivce-info.plist file
And added it in my IOS App folder. Even added it inside App/resources and App/resources/resources folder.
Also, my GoogleService-info.plist file contains a valid GOOGLE_APP_ID.

Still my build is failing with following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options.'

**Full error**

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/piyush/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cfgpruswvcmgvpcxuzeyccwfgdyx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
*** **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options.'**
CoreSimulator 776.3 - Device: iPod touch (7th generation) (4C9D1328-19EA-4266-B1FA-C5625E76EDEA) - Runtime: iOS 15.0 (19A339) - DeviceType: iPod touch (7th generation)
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: What is 'Firebace'?  Make sure the bundle identifier stated in the Google info guy matches that of the app.

Comment: I refer to Google Firebase, sorry for miss spell. Corrected the spell in my question too